# A probable bug in the "people impacted" of my profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I'm not sure if META is the right place to ask such a question. If it's not suitable for here please let me know and I'll just delete it.

My problem is with the "xxx people reached" thing in [my Math.SE profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/191404/vim). I just randomly checked my profile and really got a shock from it:

[image]

At first glance I thought I was overlooking a decimal point, but even with effort I simply couldn't find one! So I'm almost sure there is something wrong with the estimates here. As you can see, I'm a relatively newbie on this site (I love it very much and browse it on a daily basis, though) who have been a member for less than 2 years with just <5k reputation and altogether <300 posts here. Although I like regularly dropping comments under interesting posts, I don't think that would "impact" this great many people.

For confirmation I then went to checked some other veteran users (reps 10k to 40k) who have much richer experience and contributed much more than I have here, and, to my great astonishment, many of them even have lower estimates than I do! I think it's so ridiculous..

Whatever, this is not a very serious problem for this site. But for me personally, it will be very desirable to know a reasonable estimate of how many people I have reached, which is in some way an indicator of how much I have participated in or contributed to this site. I've always been very fond of and grateful to this site for all the help I've obtained from here, therefore I also wish to have a concept about how much I have done in return.

I'd be very grateful if anybody could kindly clarify or solve this problem for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got a recent vote on a CW answer to a *very* popular question, which brought your answer to a +5 score. This makes all the views on the question eligible for the impact counter.

Which is why you have such impact. If someone downvotes that answer, the number will drop by a few hundred thousands.

See also: [Massive change in 'People Reached' overnight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273828/massive-change-in-people-reached-overnight) and [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) for more information.

Comment: Oh I see... thanks. Though I still think it is much much over-estimated since very few of the views were actually given rise to by *my* post. And also thanks for the additional info.

Comment: I can downvote it, if it makes you feel any better... :-P

Comment: No, thanks : ) and  I think I'd rather keep this *secret* to myself lol

Comment: Well, someone apparently did. It wasn't me though.

Comment: I see. So sad  :(. However the good thing is I can get a more realistic stat about it, which is of course more important than the pride (vanity?) I get from the stat itself. ;)